# Карта с возможностью построения маршрута до ближайшей метки SOS

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, геолокация, yandex-maps-jsapi

Приветствую! И прошу помощи. От заказчика поступили такая задача! Необходимо автоматически указывать ближайшую к пользователю метку в городе, и прокладывать маршрут к ней или любой другой метке выбранной пользователем построение маршрута должно начинаться при нажатии на "ссылку" в hint или balloon

Как пример, методы частично реализованы на [этой](http://clck.ru/DANnD) странице, но в нем маршрут прокладывается автоматически к ближайшей метке

Подскажите направление поисков! В одиночку пока решения не нашел! Будет полезно общение в сообществом и знающими людьми, не с кем посоветоваться.
Уверен что существуют проработанные или уже  готовые решения на GitHub или ещё где-то!

P.S. на карте требуются ещё несколько функций. (все метки в городе Кемерово)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ссылка не работает

Comment: Она живая! Лечиться копированием в адресную строку или добавлением https:// https://clck.ru/DANnD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, должно быть что-то вроде такого. Пока на функции прорисовки маршрута `showRoute(){}`, застрял. Ошибка `Type Error ymaps.route is not a function`. Написал в Яндекс, может ответят, ну и сам подумаю ещё.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap, myPlaceMark;

function init() {
myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [ymaps.geolocation.latitude, ymaps.geolocation.longitude],
    zoom: 4
});
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [46.65, 32.63], {
        hintContent: 'Херсон!',
        balloonContent: '<a href=# onclick = showRoute();>Показать путь</a>'
    });
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
};

function showRoute() {
ymaps.route([
    [ymaps.geolocation.latitude, ymaps.geolocation.longitude], myPlacemark.geometry._Wd
], {
    mapStateAutoPlay: true
}).then(function(route) {
    myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
}, function(error) {
    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + error.message);
})
};
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>
        yandexapis
    </title>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard,package.route&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width 100%; height:100%; z-index: -1;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Благодарю! A определение местоположения пользователя в вас не хромает? Я не смог сделать.

Comment: У меня в свойстве center, в моём коде на компе стоит значение:  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [ymaps.geolocation.latitude, ymaps.geolocation.longitude],... Всё работало и я собирался по клику от местоположения рисовать route, но пока не работает функция. из Янедкс ответили, пока ковыряюсь

Comment: Сейчас попробую у себя поменять свойство center

Comment: смена свойств center не помогла! можешь в коде передать?

Comment: Надо подключить пакет route при подключении API яндекса. Внимательно: src="https...=package.standard,package.route&lang=ru-RU" type=... Я исправляю ответ, сейчас в тесте работает, но в jsfiddle не находит функцию, думаю из-за особенностей подключения скриптов.

Comment: Код работает по клику на ссылку. Не совсем по задаче, потому что одним из условий задачи было автоматическое подгружение ближайшей точки. Ещё мне не нравится обращение к местоположению через myPlacemark.geometry._Wd, потому как это частное свойство. Я запрошу в яндекс, как можно обратиться более корректно. В общем, решена половина задачи.

Comment: Такой вопрос, глядя на [пример яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation) мое местоположение определяется верно, вставляя код на хостинг все рушится! С твоим кодом так же, не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/geolocation-docpage/ "Предоставляет информацию о местоположении пользователя на основе его IP адреса". Скорее всего используется прокси сервер, или IP даётся провайдером хостинга.

Comment: Думаю что дело в провайдере! Буду меня для тестов

Comment: Обратите внимание на тот пример, https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation, что вы ссылались. Там есть свойство provider, как я понимаю, если указать 'browser', то местоположение определится относительно устройства. Всем хостинг не поменяешь :-). Ну, и ответ отметьте, всё-ж таки рабочий :-)!

Comment: Благодарю! Смена свойства provider помогло, но на стороне хостинга все без изменений, нужно в любом случае менять. Я новичок здесь, про Отметки не знал!

Comment: Я тоже "Новичок" :-) Даже не знаю как вы поставили ссылку в "пример яндекса". Вообще, думаю,  для корректного определения местоположения пользователя всегда надо использовать данные устройства. Успехов!

Comment: Хотелось бы продолжить общение, будет нужна интеграция вашего кода к моим потугам. (За вознаграждение) Предлагаю перенести общение в Телеграм

Comment: А ссылка пишется с помощью разметки Markdown, таким образом: [Текст ссылки](http://  адрес ссылки)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Насколько я знаю, Telegramm сейчас блокируется, не возникнут ли сбои? Вот моя страница [VK](https://vk.com/dryzhakov).Можно ВК продолжить. Если по техническим причинам только Telegramm, то напишите, я зарегистрируюсь там. Постараюсь быть полезным.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Как я понимаю, вы из Украины, у вас же VK уже давно заблокирован. Есть неиспользуемая мной страница [Lipcev](http://vk.com/Lipcev), А Телеграм буду использовать в любом случае, мой логин @Lipcev [Lipcev](http://t.me/Lipcev)